# ko.obserable ignore change if cancelled selected on edit

Tags: knockout.js, observable

I'm pretty new to KO. However if I am correct, model.firstName is observed for any changes:

```
model.firstName = ko.observable(src.firstName)
```

My issue is I don't know how to revert back to the original if someone presses cancel on my 'Edit' screen (modal), for example:

- Click to edit
- Clear first name field
- Click cancel
- Click to edit again
- First name field is blank

The edit is a `model`. Im unsure how I would reset it?

```
onCancel: function () {            
            this.show(false);
            // revert back to value provided on load?
            model.firstName(src.firstName);
        },
```

Comment: you should probably maintain the data you get from server onLoad in a separate `js variable` so you can access it later to reset it . As far i see you can maintain the previous value via `beforeChange` (only last changed value it has ) but getting you the server value with no additional server call i prefer my initial detail .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a protectedObservable:

Model:

```
model.firstName = ko.protectedObservable(src.firstName);
model.save = function() {
   model.firstName.commit();
}
model.cancel = function() {
   model.firstName.reset();
}
```

HTML:

```
<input data-bind="value: firstName" />
<button data-bind="click: cancel">Cancel</button>
<button data-bind="click: save">Save</button>
```

Extension:

```
//wrapper to an observable that requires accept/cancel
ko.protectedObservable = function(initialValue) {
    //private variables
    var _actualValue = ko.observable(initialValue),
        _tempValue = initialValue;

    //computed observable that we will return
    var result = ko.computed({
        //always return the actual value
        read: function() {
           return _actualValue();
        },
        //stored in a temporary spot until commit
        write: function(newValue) {
             _tempValue = newValue;
        }
    }).extend({ notify: "always" });

    //if different, commit temp value
    result.commit = function() {
        if (_tempValue !== _actualValue()) {
             _actualValue(_tempValue);
        }
    };

    //force subscribers to take original
    result.reset = function() {
        _actualValue.valueHasMutated();
        _tempValue = _actualValue();   //reset temp value
    };

    return result;
};
```

For further Information, read this article:
[KnockMeOut](http://www.knockmeout.net/2011/03/guard-your-model-accept-or-cancel-edits.html)

Comment: @ClareBarrington looks like a way(i haven't tested tough) but why write such fancy code for simple scenarios . simpler the better . hope you checked my comment above #pragmatic approach .

Comment: @supercool - ignoring the extension (which is wrote once and saved as a js file called for example knockout.extensions.js) your approach is very similar apart from mine is all knockout. You have to declare a temp variable as were mine is taking care by the extension. You will have to write the the save and cancel method also. But again this is taking care of using the extension. And looks alot cleaner and can be resused again as where your way long term would end up with x amount of temporary variables. But still valid if wanted once off fix.